# Prove that this set is σ-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

does anyone know how to prove this?

Let $(Ω, A, μ)$ be a measure space and $f : Ω → [0, ∞]$ $A$-measurable such that $\int_Ω{fdμ} < ∞$. Prove that the set
$Ω_+^f :=$ {${x ∈ Ω:f (x) > 0}$} is $σ$-finite.

So it is the same as proving that there exists $(E_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}} ⊂ A$ such that $Ω_+^f = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^∞ E_{n}$ and $μ(E_n)<∞$ for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$. But I don't know how to prove the latter.

Comment: Ever heard of Chebychev's inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Set $E_n=\{x:f(x)\geq\frac{1}{n}\}$. Each $E_n$ has finite measure by Markov's inequality.

Comment: I'm not very sure how to use Markov's inequality, when can you remove the absolut value from Markov's inequality? Is this correct: $μ(E_n)= μ(\{x∈Ω:f(x)\geq\frac{1}{n}\}) <= n* \int_Ω{fdμ} < ∞$ ?

Comment: The function in your question is non-negative, so you don't need to worry about the absolute value. The inequality looks good to me.